# iOS Simulator displaying white screen (only in simulator, screen shot shows UI)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

After researching previous topics on this issue, I can't seem to find an answer for my problem.

Xcode Version Version 6.1.1 (6A2008a), OS X Yosemite Version 10.10.2 (14C109)

I just finished creating my first simple application in Xcode using the Single View App template, but cannot get the iOS simulator to get past a blank white screen, no matter how long I wait.

Here's a screen shot of my main.storyboard UI/Assistant editor:

[image: main.storyboard]

It will however sometimes display the copyright information.

Here's what I've tried already:

1. Made sure my Main Interface was set to Main (main.storyboard)
2. Waited for an hour+ for iOS simulator to load and it never did
3. Tried Reset Content and Settings in the iOS simulator and then tried simulator again
4. Tried different devices besides iPhone 6 as target devices to simulate and I was able to get the iPhone 5s simulator to display the button, but only the button.
5. Uninstalled Xcode by moving to the bin, emptied trash, reinstalled from App Store

Now it gets even more strange, If I run the simulator using iPhone 6 as my target device and take a screen shot of my simulation, every object appears normally in the screen shot but NOT in the simulator (still just a blank white screen). Here's that screen shot:

[image: screenshot]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Give the main view a background color to see if it shows up. I think your view is being loaded, but your UI elements are off screen due to incorrect constraints.

Comment: @rdelmar Thanks, I appreciate the quick response! I changed the background color and then moved the elements and now it's working! Thank you for ending my grief!